# C# using buffer with different types (double, uint, ushort) but same name

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I am making changes to a data acquisition program with a buffer where the type depends on user input from the form. At the moment the same code is written 3 times except the buf variable used in the following code is declared differently. The next lines of code are the same. The code snippet below is used 3 times which makes the code bigger then needed. **How can i declare the buf variable without type, then give it a type in the if structures and write the code using the buf var only 1 time?** I'm new to C# and tried declaring as void and casting in the ifs like I learned in java but can't seem to find a solution...

Thanks in advance

```
if(...){
      double[] buf = olBuffer.GetDataAsVolts(); 
      /* 
      or ushort[] buf = olBuffer.GetDataAsRawUInt16(); 
      or ushort[] buf = olBuffer.GetDataAsRawUInt16();
      */
}
//lots of code using the buf var
```

Comment: This is C#.  Variables always have a type.

Comment: You can´t. There´s no common base-class for `double[]`, `short[]` and all the others. Please show what you *actually* do after the definition of `buf`.

Comment: You could use `object[]` instead of the type, but be aware of boxing/unboxing. If you are doing mathematical operations on it, it becomes much more difficult. I would just pick the widest type and cast them back to the narrow type later.

Comment: Without knowing the *common* things to do we cannot give you any solution to this. As already mentioned there´s not much you can do with *every* possible array-type, except just *iterating* the array.

Comment: @HimBromBeere after that the buf is used to create a DataTable and a plot so the only things done with buf are a .length and looping trough the items to put it in the DataTable

Comment: Why not just give the arrays different names?

Comment: If all you´re doing with the array is to *iterate* it, you could declare `buf` as `IEnumerable` or as `Array` in front.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your logic and whether you need to do any operations specific to `int`, `short` or whatever types you use - such as basic mathematical operations.

If you don't need such operations, you can declare a method like this and pass it your buffer:

```
private void WorkWithBuffer<T>(T[] buffer) {
    // lots of code with your buffer
}
```

Comment: That assumes you *have* some common-base class or interface all the instances in the array inherit from/implement, which is unlikely in case of numeric types. There´s no common numeric base-type.

Comment: Same here. Thank you for the info. I'll try it when I'm able to use the hardware again next week.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. Very bad ones like dynamic (that are so bad, that I won't describe it as it would lead you in the wrong direction).

And better ones like object[]. While I encourage you to check if **you really need to store different types in one variable**, you can declare it as object[]:

```
object[] buf =olBuffer.GetDataAsVolts();
```

You will have to cast that data later, when you want to use it:

```
double[] dbuf=(double[])buf;
```

Maybe you don't really save the data in different types, but internally can always work with the same type. So simply casting it to a type that allows both values could be even more useful.

double should be able to store your ushort-values to. You can simply cast or convert it:

```
double dValue=(double) ushortValue
```

or

```
double dValue=Convert.ToDouble(uShortValue)
```

But be sure, that the ranges and precision matches your requirements before casting that way.

But again: Check if there is a better way by using the correct type. C# variables always require a type.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've written some code doing as you suggested and when I'm able to use the hardware again next week I'll try it out.